# Finding minimum value within adjacent locations of array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, multidimensional-array, maze

I'm new to coding and have not been coding for more than two months.
For my assignment, I'm making an escape the maze algorithm.
The **user defines a 2D array and a start point**, then the program must take the least damaging route to find its way out. The "AI" can **only move north, east, south, or west**. It can escape from any edge of the array.

```
Enter the starting x coordinate: 2 
Enter the starting y coordinate: 4 
0 1 4 2 6 0 1  
1 7 4 2 2 6 0  
0 0 0 8 * 4 1  
1 1 2 7 3 4 2  
5 1 6 4 2 2 1
```

In this example, the user has selected [2,4] as the start location of the array (remember, indexing begins at 0).
The AI can escape from any edge of the array. It is going to want to pick the smallest integer for each movement. For this example, the AI will move up to 2, then left, then up. Thus it took a sum amount of "6 damage" to exit the array.

My issue is comparing whether North is smaller than East, and if North is smaller than East, is it smaller than West? Or South? If East is smaller than North, is it smaller than West? Or South? & so on and so forth.
I'm not sure whether I'm going about this in the correct manner.
**My attempt can be found at lines 44 - 78 in the hastebin link below.**
I have no idea what I'm doing.

I created an `int minimumValue;` but I'm not sure how to utilize it, or where. If `boardArray[north][currentY] < boardArray[east][currentY]` then `boardArray[north][currentY]` is my new minimum value correct? Then I would need to write code comparing that to west and south as well. I feel like there has to be a simpler method to go about it.

I've tried googling solutions, Reddit, The Coding Den discord server, but I simply can't get this down.

Any and all help will be appreciated!

https://hastebin.com/acopoborut.java

Comment: what's "least damaging route" and how can you compare "whether North is smaller than East" ? the definitions of the problem are not clear.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. What alfasin said is true. Your problem definition is not clear. Update your answer with the details you posted in the comment section. Also, post the code snippets that you believe to be important while defining the problem in the question itself, like you said lines 44 - 78. That will help others quickly go through what you have tried so far.

Comment: You still haven't explain what does "least damaging route" mean, route from where to where? where is the entry point and where are the exit point? how do you determine them. As Sajib wrote: please improve the description of the problem in the post itself *not* in the comments section. If you won't bother making your question easy to understand and follow through people will not bother to help you... Help us help you!

Comment: I have edited my original post! I apologize. I hope I explained better this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Holy nested else's Batman!

I would replace lines 55-78 with something like this:

```
//find the least danger:
int leastDanger = northDanger;
if(southDanger < leastDanger) leastDanger = southDanger;
if(eastDanger  < leastDanger) leastDanger = eastDanger;
if(westDanger  < leastDanger) leastDanger = westDanger;
// Go the first direction equal to least danger 
if      (northDanger == leastDanger) { moveNorth
}else if(southDanger == leastDanger) { moveSouth
}else if(eastDanger  == leastDanger) { moveEast
}else if(westDanger  == leastDanger) { moveWest
}
```

The moveDirections would be your code like

```
visitedPath = visitedPath + "[" + currentX + "," + currentY + "]";
```

And the danger values are your code like

```
boardArray[north][currentY]
```

It could also be done with a switch statement, if you know those.

Comment: This is due in 20 minutes, I took too long to consult Stackoverflow so I'm just going to end up taking a partial credit.
However I'd still like to complete this for my own learning's sake.
Now, I completely considered setting my minValue (leastDanger) to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` initially, but what if someone testing edge cases decides they want to enter ridiculous integers in their array?
What happens when northDanger and eastDanger are the same integer?

Comment: Starting at Integer.MAX_VALUE is a great idea.  Users would not be able to enter ridiculous values larger than that into the array.  If coded as above, it would take the first direction that matches the leastDanger.  So it would go North if northDanger and eastDanger were both equal to leastDanger.

Comment: I see. Thank you! I'll try and figure it out from here. I appreciate it a lot!
May report back if this doesn't pan out the way it's flowing in my head right now.

Answer (score 0):

I assume by saying north you refer to -y direction and east you refer to +x direction

if `boardArray[x][y]` represent coordinate (x,y), then the coordinate north of it should be (x,y-1) and east is (x+1,y). You can compare them like this

```
boardArray[x][y-1] < boardArray[x+1][y] //Is North smaller than East?
```

Of course you should first check if the north and east are both inside the array, otherwise you will get `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException`

Comment: Ah are my parameters for N/E/S/W backwards? My apologies. I was under the impression that x+-1 corresponds to up and down.
Okay so I did the comparison correctly.
But then what happens when North isn't smaller than east? 
Won't I need another line of code asking if(`boardArray[x+1][y] < boardArray[x][y-1]`? That becomes redundant does it not? Is there a shortcut?

Comment: If you are using `if-else` statement to check "north<east", than "north>=east" will just fall to the `else` block. In your question you just said that you would continue to compare north to west and south but you didn't mention what happens if "north>=east"

Comment: Also east should be `boardArray[currentX][east]`  instead of `boardArray[east][currentY]` since you made the y-axis the west and east

Comment: It needs to just pick the smallest value, that's why I'm trying to compare everything. Is there an easy way to look at all 4 values surrounding the "current position" simultaneously, then pick the smallest one? I feel like the way I'm doing it is the hard way.The way I'm doing it, I'm going to need like 15-20 if-else statements. :/ when north >= east falls into the else block, i'll have to have an if else within that else block to compare to south or west, and then ANOTHER if else within that nested else to compare for the final direction.
Also thank you again, good catch on [x][east].

Comment: Utilize your `minimumValue`: If you start from North, you can set it to North and compare it to the other 3 directions one by one. If the next direction is smaller, set `minimumValue` to that direction, otherwise keep it. This is the straight-forward way to find a minimum/maximum.